# Defining a 'compound' style in CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to define a CSS style such that it includes another by default?

For example, take the following classes:

```
.rounded{
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.box{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
}
```

Instead of writing `<div class="rounded box">` everywhere on the site (which would probably lead to less consistency and would almost definitely lead to long strings of classes in the html), can I define `.box` to automatically include `.rounded`?

This has implications for redundancy in the CSS and CSS tags - I'd rather not have to specify border-radii each time I come to an element in a new situation or context that could, for example, incorporate `.big_rounded`, `.med_rounded` or `.small_rounded`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is given by [Melv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213968/defining-a-compound-style-in-css/5213987#5213987), however CSS doesn't support true inheritance.

Alternatively, there are tools/frameworks that extend CSS syntax. Two popular ones I know of are [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Among their many benefits are "mixins" that allow for CSS inheritance. You use framework's syntax to indicate inheritance and the tools generate the CSS.

LESS example:

```
.rounded{
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.box{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  .rounded; /* This is a mixin */
}
```

Comment: how do LESS and SASS compare in your opinion?

Comment: @sscirrus - I've only done some light research into each of them. The (perhaps wrong) impression I get is that LESS is more lightweight and standalone while SASS is part of a larger project that includes HAML. So while SASS might have more active development, it carries some dependency baggage with it. Also, LESS seems more used in ASP.NET circles. That said, both are language-independent enough to be integrated into a variety of development environments.

Comment: after doing more research I discovered a number of additional alternatives to LESS and SASS, each of which have their own added conveniences. This is a wider field of options than I was anticipating!

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
.box, .rounded {
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.box {
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
}
```

Comment: I think that this is the simple answer, however selector inheritance would also be a great solution to this problem. CSS does not support inheritance so thats where SASS comes in which has already been mentioned by @greg